# Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows' - terraform(CustomScriptExtension)

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating these below extensions as part of a vm module through terraform.
The first extension (customScript Extenison) gets created.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "dsm_activate" {
  name                 = "DSM-Activation_Extension"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_machine.vm]

  settings = <<-BASE_SETTINGS
  {
     "fileUris": ["https://sstsv2xxxxxxxtmztf.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/windows_dsm_activate.ps1"]
  }
BASE_SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<-PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File windows_dsm_activate.ps1",
    "storageAccountName": "${var.storage_account}",
    "storageAccountKey": "${var.storage_account_key}"
  }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "initialize_disk" {
  name                  = "Initialize-Disk-VMExtension"
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher             = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                  = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version  = "1.10"
  depends_on            = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.vm","azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.dsm_activate", "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.da_extension","azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.nw_extension"]

 
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
    }
SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell Initialize-Disk -FriendlyName (Get-Disk -Number 2).FriendlyName -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru; powershell New-Partition -DiskNumber (Get-Disk -Number 2).DiskNumber -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize; powershell Format-Volume -DriveLetter F -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'DATA' -Confirm:0"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

However the code fails when it tries to exceute the second customScriptExtension with following error:

```
Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input
```

How to modify the above script to have both custom script gets executed.

Comment: If you can figure how to perform create-delete-create-delete sequence for multiple CustomScriptExtension-s, then that hack should be feasible. See https://mitesh1612.github.io/blog/2021/05/14/vms-with-multiple-extensions

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#extension-schema) this isn't supported.  See the note

> Only one version of an extension can be installed on a VM at a point
> in time, specifying custom script twice in the same Resource Manager
> template for the same VM will fail.

It isn't entirely clear if it is two versions since you are using version 1.9 and 1.10, or two extensions.  Regardless given the additional examples provided, I would suggest you take the code example in the second extension, and create a file to include in your first extension fileUris.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple script execution is supported, but you need to embedded those execution within one master powershell file.

Simply create powershell file where you execute two other files like described in documentation:

- [Custom Script Extension for Windows - Using multiple scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#using-multiple-scripts)